# Alternative UI for Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls

Suppose I have a list of data to be displayed. I know how to display it using a `ListView` And it is very simple and easy to do it that way. But I am looking for an alternative way to achieve the same. I don't expect to have more than 20 items in the data set I am planning for.

I was thinking of a number of squares that the user can swipe to see the next one etc, similar to some widgets on home screen.

I came across [android.widget.StackView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html), any advice available for this?

Comment: Swipe vertically or horizontally? One or multiple squares displayed at a time? Square content(only image/only text/image+text)?

Comment: `Gallery` and `GridView` are there too. Hope you already have considered them.

Comment: this is not a research, i just wanted to implement something in a new way. and i wont have more than 20 or 30 items, but they will be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try StackView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html).

This is how the Gallery and Youtube widgets are rendered.

Comment: This is a new type of view that can be used for small sets of data I guess and acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

ListView is the best option for listing lots of data. It has very efficient loading property. But if you do not want it any specific reason, you have to use ScrollView and in ScrollView, you have to place a LinearLayout and in that LinearLayout, you have to place multiple LinearLayout(for each items of data).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a `ViewPager` (available also for lower versions of SDK through compatibility pack).
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html - see also the project example top right of the page : EffectiveNavigation.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GridView`, if you want to show multiple items on a page in a different fashion than in `ListView`.

You can also use `ViewPager` (from android 3.0, or with the support library) with your custom views.